# upgrading to electric, then what

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have diamondback installed. After I upgrade to Electric should I delete the OPT/ROS/DIAMONDBACK directory? what is the usual thing to do after an upgrade?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11285/upgrading-to-electric,-then-what/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to the other answers about how to remove Diamondback using

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-diamondback-*
```

you could choose to leave both Diamondback and Electric installed in `/opt/ros`. You can select which ROS version your packages will use by modifying a line in your `~/.bashrc` file. If you were using Diamondback previously there should be a line like

```
source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
```

To switch to Electric change that line to

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

You can only have one of those uncommented at a time (use `#` to comment one of them out). Then, either restart the terminal or run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

That command needs to be run in each terminal (and terminal tab) that you have open. After switching that line you have to rebuild your packages so they use the current version. This is mostly so that the messages are all in the correct format. But, the point is that you can safely leave Diamondback installed after you install Electric.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both versions are independent of each other. You may remove the old one if you have no further use for it.

Note that if you have installed ROS with your OS package manager, you should deinstall the packages instead of just deleting the directories. For Ubuntu, deinstalling everything with ros-diamondback in the name should do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-09-22**:
Basically we gave the same answer at the same time :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual thing is at least recompile all your packages (the ones that didn't ship with electric) to check if some dependencies are broken (most of the time they will be as message definitions are moved around). If no everything works fine and you are comfortable with the new distribution, you can safely remove diamondback. Unless you compiled ROS from source you should use the package manager of your distribution. In any case avoid manually deleting the files, always try to use the package manager.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1